# Describe this command "find home/ -mtime +25 -exec rm -rf {} \; 2> /dev/null"

Tags: linux, shell-script, find

```
find /home/ -mtime +25 -exec rm -rf {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

what is the output the above command and how it is worked

what is `-exec` `{}` `\;` in the command

Comment: Please do `man find` and  search for the explanation of the `-exec` option. If it's still not clear, ask specifically for what is not understood.

Answer (score 4):

The command in question finds any *name* (of a file, directory or otherwise) under `/home` (including `/home` itself) that have a modification time of at least 25 days ago, and deletes these names.  If the name refers to a directory, then the whole directory tree is deleted.

No output is produced since none of the involved commands writes to standard output and since diagnostic messages are redirected to `/dev/null`. The `find` utility may generate error messages that won't be seen, if it tries to process directories that have already been deleted. Using `-depth` ensures that the directory tree is processed bottom up rather than from top to bottom.

`-exec` will be used by `find` to call an external command. The `{}` will be replaced by the found name and `\;` signals the end of the external command.

---

Note that the command will also *match and recursively delete `/home` itself*, if it's old enough. The modification timestamp on directories only updates if files or directories *immediately* under the directory are added or deleted, so unless you've done that within the last 25 days, I would expect the command to delete `/home` and all its contents if it's run with root privileges.

Adding or removing files within subdirectories of `/home` does not update the timestamp of `/home`.

If run with non-root privileges, then all files, directories etc. under `/home` that belong to the current user would be deleted if they or any of their parent directories (e.g. `/home`) are old enough.

---

If you only intend to remove *regular files*, then I would suggest

```
find /home -type f -mtime +25 -exec rm -f {} +
```

It's the `-type f` test that will only let through regular files.  Using `-exec ... {} +` rather than `-exec ... {} \;` means that as few invocations as possible of `rm` will occur (several names will be collected and passed in `{}`).

Or, if your `find` supports `-delete`:

```
find /home -type f -mtime +25 -delete
```

To see what gets deleted, insert `-print` before `-exec` (or before `-delete`).  To interactively be prompted for each removal, use `-ok` in place of `-exec` (don't use `-delete` in this case and don't redirect standard error to `/dev/null`).

Comment: I think `rm -rf /home` will blow out your own home directory (the contents), even though it can't  touch `/home` (or `/home/user`) itself, right?

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes. `/home` and `$HOME` themselves would be safe, but the files under `$HOME` would not be safe.

Comment: @roaima I added some text regarding this just now.

Answer (score 0):

this is a action done on the found patterns
here is find in /home any file with mtime over 25 days and those are deleted

mtime is modified time as number*24 hours ago.

-exec command on {} who represents the found patterns & \; is end of command marker